# Node.js Lambda Function Not Working When Downloading S3 File

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to follow the AWS Lambda examples to download an S3 file and process the results, but I keep getting the following error message in my results:

```
Process exited before completing request
```

My code is as follows:

```
'use strict';

var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

console.log('Loading event');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Getting values from event.');
    var tenant = event.tenant;
    var key = event.key

    async.waterfall([
        function download(next) {
            console.log('Creating request.');
            var keyFile = "secret";
            var sourceBucket = "mybucket";
            console.log('Retrieving secret key using bucket ' + sourceBucket + ' and keyfile ' + keyFile);
            var params = {Bucket: sourceBucket, Key: key};
            s3.getObject(params, next);
        },
        function returnFile(response, next) {
            console.log('Executing returnFile.');
            // Do return stuff here.
            console.log(response);
        }, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error: ' + err);
            } else {
                console.log('Successfully completed.');
            }
            context.done();
        }
    ]);
}
```

And the log file that is returned:

```
START RequestId: 15327019-2b3b-11e5-a94b-e72d67a1fe04
2015-07-15T21:47:26.627Z    15327019-2b3b-11e5-a94b-e72d67a1fe04    Getting values from event.
2015-07-15T21:47:26.628Z    15327019-2b3b-11e5-a94b-e72d67a1fe04    Creating request.
2015-07-15T21:47:26.628Z    15327019-2b3b-11e5-a94b-e72d67a1fe04    Retrieving secret key using bucket mybucket and keyfile secret
END RequestId: 15327019-2b3b-11e5-a94b-e72d67a1fe04
REPORT RequestId: 15327019-2b3b-11e5-a94b-e72d67a1fe04  Duration: 921.08 ms Billed Duration: 1000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 14 MB  
Process exited before completing request
```

I'm a little stumped as to how to further troubleshoot this issue. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Ok, thanks for the responses. I was incorrectly using the async waterfall method. I wasn't calling the callbacks correctly, and I didn't correctly specify the callback for the waterfall method. Below is the working code if anyone runs into a similar issue:

```
'use strict';

var waterfall = require('async-waterfall');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var keyFile = "secret";
var sourceBucket = "mybucket";

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Loading event');
    console.log('Getting values from event.');
    var fileType = event.fileType;
    var key = event.key;
    console.log('fileType: "' + fileType + '", key: "' + key + '"');

    waterfall([
        function downloadSecret(next) {
            console.log('Retrieving secret key using bucket "' + sourceBucket + '" and keyfile "' + keyFile + '"');
            var params = {Bucket: sourceBucket, Key: keyFile};
            s3.getObject(params, next);
        },
        function extractKey(response, next) {
            console.log('Executing checkKey.');
            var secretKey = response.Body.toString('utf-8').trim();

            console.log('key: "' + key + '", secretKey: "' + secretKey + '"');
            if (key!=secretKey) {
                context.fail("Invalid key specified.");
            } else {
                next();
            }
        },
        function getFile(next) {
            console.log('Executing getFile.');
            var file;
            if (fileType == "1") {
                file = "file1";
            } else {
                file = "file2";
            }
            console.log('file: "' + file + '"');
            var params = {Bucket: sourceBucket, Key: file};
            s3.getObject(params, next);
        },
        function returnFile(response) {
            console.log('Executing returnFile.');
            var output = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log(output);
            context.succeed(response.Body.toString('utf-8').trim());
        }
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Any chance that your code failed to handle an exception which caused the Lambda function to exit before context.done/fail/succeed was called? Maybe you could try the s3-get-object blueprint that Amazon provides and build up from there.

Comment: So, the problem was that a) my callback handler syntax wasn't set correctly, and b) you have to explicitly call the next callback method in each waterfall function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're using the `async` library incorrectly. The `returnFile` function callback parameters seem incorrect.

Also, make sure your `Lambda` has proper permissions to access the bucket granted via it's `IAM Policy`. Then you don't need to supply your access credentials to the `AWS SDK`, it will pull them automatically.

Comment: Yup. This was absolutely the issue. I had some basic syntax errors and usage that wasn't in line with the library.